# Is it possible to particular id count and subtract from another table with only one query in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to count `clinic_id` rows from `sms_history` table and that are subtract from sms `total_available_sms` column from `sms` table in one query.

**sms_history table**
[image: [sms_history table]

**sms table**
[image: sms table]

**users table**
[image: users table]

I want to display record in table like that :

```
Client Id  Client Name           Available sms   Total SMS
---------  -------------------   --------------  ---------
2          Krishna Dental Care   196             200
```

I am trying to do something like this

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('sms');
$query = $this->db->get();
$total_available = $query->result();


foreach ($total_available as $sms) {

//get clinic id
$clinic_id = $sms->clinic_id;

//get total available sms
$total_available = $sms->total_available;

$count = $this->db->where('clinic_id',$clinic_id)->from("sms_history")->count_all_results();

//get finaly count sms
$final_count_sms = $total_available - $count;


// get clinics from user table
$this->db->where('clinic_id', $clinic_id);
$q = $this->db->get('users');
$data = $q->result_array();

// get clinic name
$clinic_name = $data[0]['clinic_name'];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is possible in one query:

Try following query:

```
SELECT ( SELECT total_available FROM sms WHERE clinic_id = '1' ) - COUNT( sms_history.clinic_id) FROM sms_history JOIN sms ON sms_history.clinic_id= sms.clinic_id
```

If you have multiple ids then do following,

You have clinc_id in you sms_history is 1,2.

So you can make array of it like:

```
$ids = array('1','2');
for($i = 0 ; $i <= $ids.length; $i++)
{

      $sql = "SELECT ( SELECT total_available FROM sms WHERE clinic_id = '".$ids[i]."' ) - COUNT( sms_history.clinic_id) FROM sms_history JOIN sms ON sms_history.clinic_id= sms.clinic_ids WHERE sms_history.clinic_id =  '".$ids[i]."'";
      /* after your generate your query you will get substration of it. so at same time you need to fire update query for "available_message" */

}
```

Try above code i hope this will work for you.

Comment: thanks parth, client id is multple like `1,2,3` then ?

Comment: Update question and show your records are stored in table with multiple ids.

Comment: each time you want "available message" you have run this query and you have to pass your id in query. or else you can make array like "id = array (<your ids as array element>)" then you have to use for loop and when you get each id you can pass this query.

Comment: when i have reun `$query->result(); ` then i have display that type `Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [( SELECT total_available FROM sms WHERE clinic_id = 1 ) - COUNT( sms_history.clinic_id)] => 494 ) )`

Comment: i want to only 494

Comment: I have update my answer check it . i hope you will get idea what you have to done.

Comment: Hii Parth get result is wrong `494` but actual result is` 496 (500 - 2)`

Comment: I have update my query. You need to add only WHERE clause in your query.

Comment: This query will give you 196 for clinic_id 2 and 498 for clinic_id 1